# Add machine and/or actual user name on changing status in JIRA

Tags: jira

My JIRA is mapped to AD and users are normally using their windows login to log into JIRA. However, there are certain group emails too which have access to log into JIRA. So if someone using the group email ID logs in and changes the status, the user name in history section contains only the group's name.

I want to add the machine name from which the group ID was used and/or the actual windows user name who logged into JIRA. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can do that without develop a rather complicated plugin.

The plugin basically need to either change username upon login, or display extra info in history tab.

Can you just remove permission on these group emails, so they can't change status?